# Type annotations needed for Result<_, E>

Tags: rust

In this code:

```
use notify::{RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Result, Watcher};
use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res| match res {
        Ok(event) => println!("event: {:?}", event.paths),
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
    })?;

    // Get the current directory as a PathBuf
    let current_dir: PathBuf = env::current_dir()?;

    // Append the 'temp' directory to the current directory path
    let temp_dir = current_dir.join("temp");

    println!("Watching for changes in: {:?}", temp_dir);

    // Add the temp directory to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    watcher.watch(&temp_dir, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    println!("Watching for changes. Press Enter to stop...");

    let mut input = String::new();

    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?; // Blocks here until Enter is pressed

    Ok(())
}
```

I get this error:

```
12 |     let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res| match res {
   |                                                    ^^^
13 |         Ok(event) => println!("event: {:?}", event.paths),
   |                                              ----- type must be known at this point
```

If I do what the Rust compiler suggests:

```
12 |     let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res: Result<_, E>| match res {
   |                                                       ++++++++++++++
```

I get another error:

```
type alias takes 1 generic argument but 2 generic arguments were supplied
expected 1 generic argument
```

[Live code](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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) on Rust Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `use notify::Result` up top (which takes one argument) is hiding `std::result::Result` (which takes two).

This is how it compiles:

```
use notify::{Event, RecommendedWatcher, RecursiveMode, Result, Watcher};
use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Automatically select the best implementation for your platform.
    let mut watcher = notify::recommended_watcher(|res: std::result::Result<Event, _> | match res {
        Ok(event) => println!("event: {:?}", event.paths),
        Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
    })?;

    // Get the current directory as a PathBuf
    let current_dir: PathBuf = env::current_dir()?;

    // Append the 'temp' directory to the current directory path
    let temp_dir = current_dir.join("temp");

    println!("Watching for changes in: {:?}", temp_dir);

    // Add the temp directory to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    watcher.watch(&temp_dir, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

    println!("Watching for changes. Press Enter to stop...");

    let mut input = String::new();

    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?; // Blocks here until Enter is pressed

    Ok(())
}
```